# WMI and C# - no result

Tags: c#, wmi

I have the following code and try to find the MAC address of the AP. The code runs, but it does not return anything. What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
using System;
using System.Management;

public class wifiTest
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM MSNDis_80211_BSSIList";
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root/WMI", query);
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = searcher.Get();
        ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator moe = moc.GetEnumerator();
        moe.MoveNext();
        ManagementBaseObject[] objarr = (ManagementBaseObject[])moe.Current.Properties["Ndis80211BSSIList"].Value;
        foreach (ManagementBaseObject obj in objarr)
        {
            uint u_rssi = (uint)obj["Ndis80211Rssi"];
            int rssi = (int)u_rssi;    

            int macAd = (int)obj["Ndis80211MacAddress"];

            Console.WriteLine("RSSI=" + rssi);
            Console.WriteLine("Mac=" + macAd);               
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What might be helpful: insert a few breakpoints and debug to see if `objarr` for instance isn't empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MSNDis_80211_BSSIList` retrieve data only if the driver of your wifi adapter implements a  WMI provider for such class. for an alternative consider use the [`Native Wifi API`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705969.aspx) if you are using C# check this project [`Managed Wifi API`](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with WMI in managed code, I strongly suggest you use the [Management Strongly Typed Class Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wkebaxa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), instead of dealing with `ManagementObjectSearcher` objects and the likes directly.

> The Management Strongly Typed Class Generator tool enables you to
>   quickly generate an early-bound managed class for a specified Windows
>   Management Instrumentation (WMI) class. The generated class simplifies
>   the code you must write to access an instance of the WMI class.
>
> This tool is automatically installed with Visual Studio and with the
>   Windows SDK.

In addition, you'd might want to get familiar with [wbemtest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692770.aspx), which is a simple tool with which you can check your queries.